# Having trouble making a background image (line) span screen width with horizontal scroll

Tags: css, background

I need to create a red line that spans the entire screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/k86gc/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#redBar{ width: 100%; height: 10px; z-index: -1; margin-top: 80px; background: #D2232A;}
#heading{ width: 768px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 80px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="redBar"></div>
<div id="heading"> Heading</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that when you scroll to the right with the horizontal scroll bar the red bar does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

There's different ways of doing this. Using your approach, you could just add `position: fixed` to `#redBar`. See [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/k86gc/2/)